# console application need rebuild and deploy again after dependent project changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I have a asp.net project. The solution has a web project and a console application. The web project also host a wcf service. And the console application consume the wcf service. They works fine before. Last month I did some change to the web project, and deployed it. My question is do I have to rebuild the console application and publish it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you modified the method signatures (or modify classes that they may return) of your WCF Services that your console application consumes, then you shouldn't need to rebuild it.